# How can I install and use apps on my phone with neither of them knowing about the other?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account, privacy, google-play-services

For example I want to install app Y on my phone, but I don't want my Google account (which I'm using to use my Android) to know that I'm using the app or any information that I enter in it...and I also don't want the app to be able to pull any info from my Google and know anything other than what I directly feed it. Basically both of them living in parallel dimensions completely oblivious to one another.

How can I achieve this?

Android 7 | Moto C Plus | Rooted

Comment: This question can not be answered for generic Android apps as it depends on which services (e.g. from Google) the app uses. Therefore please reformulate the question so that is targets one app (including app name and link to the Play Store). And it may also depend son the Android version on your device. Therefore please include details about your device name, manufacturer and Android version.

Comment: Just edited the post. I'm not thinking of a particular app atm. If it is dependant on the app, what are the determining factors?

Comment: There are two options: 1) install the app in a different user account / work profile 2) block the specific APIs (e.g. the ability to get accounts on the device) through permission restrictions or even better using some framework mod like XPrivacyLua. In former case you may find my app helpful: https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX

Comment: you could [recompile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.sdcardmovable) apk so google play can not associate certificates with official app anymore. not sure this is sufficient as it is still same pkgname (can be changed with Magisk hide)

Comment: Installing packages like vim and python in Termux doesn't show up anywhere else on the android system. Getting a graphical interface though will be a huge pain. The way I know it, Linux works by looking at the /bin/ folder for binaries and installed apps so if you could install an app in for example <internal storage(i don't know the exact path)>/Downloads folder, google would possibly not find it. How you would run it though I don't know, unfortunately. Though I know this definitely works in Linux, I'm not sure if it will work on Android. Just added my 2 cents hoping it might help you.

Comment: Thank You @alecxs. Your comment provided a lot of insight and knowledge. I shall delete my comment if it is completely off track.